# Send a JsValue object to different execution context with postMessage

Tags: rust, worker, wasm-bindgen

Using `web_sys::BroadcastChannel`(broadcast channel or not I assume is the same outcome) I want to post a message that will be picked by different windows, what I tried so far was to convert my `#[wasm_bindgen]` annotated struct to a `JsValue` that I pass to the `chan.post_message(&msg.into())`.
I successfully receive an object in the other side but is a shell object like `{ptr: 1234567}` that I assume if used from the same context works as proxy to the underlying data.

Is there a way to make that JsValue be the "real" object? in the meantime as workaround I'm sending a JSON string that I need to parse in the receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

Due to wasm limitations it is not possible to share Rust's objects across different JS contexts.

You have to serialize/deserialize them every time.